# Why are my foreign key fields null after posting?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, postman, foreign-keys

I am using Java with the Spring Boot framework and a PostgreSQL (via Hibernate) database locally. I have entities User, Product and UserOrder. Each UserOrder has 4 columns: id, product_id (from Product), user_id (from User) and quantity.

I previously created a product and user with id 1. When I post via Postman and then retrieve it, product_id and user_id are null.

```
@Data
@Builder 
@NoArgsConstructor 
@AllArgsConstructor 
@Entity 
@Table(name = "_user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    private UserOrder userOrder;
}

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String price;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "product",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private UserOrder userOrder;
}

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class UserOrder {
    @Getter
    @jakarta.persistence.Id
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String quantity;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;
}
```

Example Postman body:

```
{
    "product_id":1,
    "user_id":1,
    "quantity":"50"
}
```

Changing the `OneToOne` annotation to `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` does not help. Setting `@JoinColumn(name = "user_id",nullable = false)` results in an exception.

Why are my foreign key fields null?

Comment: Shouldn't those OneToOne relationships be ManyToOne?

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help] Ask 1 question about 1 error. Telling us about other errors is not helpful. Post & documentation prose & code comments that repeat code are not helpful. Use prose & code comments to say why that code was written in terms of the application or interfaces & when it isn't obvious. PS What "one to one relationships"? Why? user:order is 1:M or M:M, order:product is M:M.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the User and Product you want to save to UserOrder actually exist in the User and Product tables in the database

Comment: "I previously created a product and user with id 1"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).